# how to update many fields in single mysql table with "where clause"?

Tags: mysql

i have table with same fields,want to update that fields,with where clause,

```
update tmp_aus_inv_data
SET cust_region= "ROTOMOULD"
WHERE division = "ROTOMOULD" ;

update tmp_aus_inv_data
SET cust_region= "Internal"
WHERE division = "EXTRUSION" and ucase(cust_region) like ucase('Internal%') ;
```

i tried with this,but not working,

```
update tmp_aus_inv_data
(set cust_region= "ROTOMOULD"),
(SET cust_region= "Internal")
WHERE division = "ROTOMOULD"  and WHERE division = "EXTRUSION" and ucase(cust_region)     like ucase('Internal%') ;
```

Comment: You mean you want to execute one `UPDATE` instead of two, and do the same thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement in your `UPDATE`, so I think you want something like this:

```
update tmp_aus_inv_data
SET cust_region 
    = case 
        when division = "ROTOMOULD" then "ROTOMOULD"
        when division = "EXTRUSION" 
            and ucase(cust_region) like ucase('Internal%')
          then "Internal"
        else cust_region
      end
 where division in ("ROTOMOULD", "EXTRUSION")
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8145c/1)

Comment: +1 for speed and readability, but you should add the where clause, since without, it will touch each record.

Comment: You're welcome, but he needs a where like: `division in ("ROTOMOULD", "EXTRUSION") and ucase(cust_region) like ucase('Internal%')`

Comment: @dan that extra logic is part of the `case` statement and will not be needed in the `where` clause. This actually does not need the `WHERE` clause since I included the `else cust_region` which will not alter the values of the records not in the first part of the `case`

Comment: I know that, but it will still touch the entries that are not having the `cust_region` like `Internal%` :).

Comment: @bluefeet thanks,"case" statement solves all my problems,& "else" statement retains what was before..thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Can you please try the below query once.

```
UPDATE tmp_aus_inv_data
   SET `cust_region`= if(`division`= 'ROTOMOULD', 'ROTOMOULD', 'Internal') 
WHERE division in ('ROTOMOULD','EXTRUSION');
```

Comment: ,correct,but if i want to update about 10 things in similar fields,then it creates problem,i think "if" will not work...